# How to set caret to the correct position?

Tags: codeblocks

When i do this:

```
void test(){|}
```

The caret is between `{}`, and then i press enter and this happen:

```
void test(){
|}
```

This is the problem, when i create a method, the caret is always before `}`, so i have to press enter again and again, just to put the caret in the right place.

What i want is exactly what happen with `if()`:

```
if(){|}
```

And after press enter:

```
if(){
   |
}
```

How can i make sure that the position of the caret, for any method, looks like the position of the caret in `if()` method?

I'm using codeblocks 16.01.
Thank you.